# How to parse a specific part of a string to individual columns in sql?

Tags: sql, string, parsing, ssms

I need to take a part of a field in a table and parse it out to two fields in sql. I currently use MS SSMS. At this point I only want to do this with a select statement. The fields will have a varying amount of text.

I am very familiar with using regular expressions so maybe there's a way to go about it that way with a select?

Here's what I'm trying now:

```
SELECT
replace(Column1, '(.*)(,\s)(.*)(\s)(HRS)(\.)','$1') Column1,
replace(Column1, '(.*)(,\s)(.*)(\s)(HRS)(\.)','$3') Column2,
replace(Column1, '(.*)(,\s)(.*)(\s)(HRS)(\.)','$5') Column3
FROM Table1
Where Column1 like '%HRS.%'
```

my result is just Column1 duplicated into columns 2 and 3

I want my result to look like this:

```
         Column1                               Column 2    Column 3
ROW 1    BKT, CAB, TIRES                       250         HRS
ROW 2    FRONT BKT, REAR BKT, CAB, TRACKS      1,234       HRS
ROW 3    FORKS, MAST, CAB, 20 HP ENG, TIRES    25,102      HRS
```

Comment: What kind of database are you using?  Which version?

Comment: I found out i can't do this in Heidi so I downloaded MS SSMS and it will allow it but i still can't quite figure out the right way do execute this. I'll edit my question with what I have so far:

Comment: Ok, so clearly you're using SQL Server.  Unfortunately, the "REGEXP_REPLACE" function shown in my original answer isn't available in SQL Server - and "REPLACE"
 (as shown in your revised post) does something different and won't work here. I have revised my answer below accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

**Revised answer to show how this could be done in SQL Server.**

First, we create this function as shown here (credits to Cade Bryant, author of this article):

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/find-the-nth-occurrence-of-a-character-in-a-string

Then, we apply a strategy of reversing the string and chopping it up into the three columns.  Note that for column 3, the first character of the reversed string is removed before it is un-reversed. This removes the "." from "HRS." If there are cases where the original string doesn't end with a ".", then the approach will need to be tweaked.

```
SELECT REVERSE(
         SUBSTRING(
           REVERSE(column1),
           dbo.CHARINDEX2(' ', REVERSE(column1), 2) + 2,
           LEN(REVERSE(column1)) - dbo.CHARINDEX2(' ', REVERSE(column1), 2) + 1
         )
       ) Column1,
       REVERSE(
         SUBSTRING(
           REVERSE(column1),
           dbo.CHARINDEX2(' ', REVERSE(column1), 1),
           dbo.CHARINDEX2(' ', REVERSE(column1), 2) - dbo.CHARINDEX2(' ', REVERSE(column1), 1)
         )
       ) Column2,
       REVERSE(
         SUBSTRING(REVERSE(column1), 2, dbo.CHARINDEX2(' ', REVERSE(column1), 1) - 2)
       ) Column3
  FROM data

|                            Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
|------------------------------------|---------|---------|
|                    BKT, CAB, TIRES |    250  |     HRS |
|   FRONT BKT, REAR BKT, CAB, TRACKS |  1,234  |     HRS |
| FORKS, MAST, CAB, 20 HP ENG, TIRES | 25,102  |     HRS |
```

REGEXP_REPLACE would be helpful here if SQL Server supported it, like MySQL 8.0 and modern Oracle versions do.  The syntax differs between database platform, but the concept is the same.  Below is an example from  MySQL 8.0:

```
mysql> select * from data;
+-------------------------------------------------+
| column1                                         |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| BKT, CAB, TIRES, 250 HRS.                       |
| FRONT BKT, REAR BKT, CAB, TRACKS, 1,234 HRS.    |
| FORKS, MAST, CAB, 20 HP ENG, TIRES, 25,102 HRS. |
+-------------------------------------------------+


mysql> SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(column1, '(.*)(, )(.* )(.*)(\.$)','$1') column1,
    ->        REGEXP_REPLACE(column1, '(.*)(, )(.* )(.*)(\.$)','$3') column2,
    ->        REGEXP_REPLACE(column1, '(.*)(, )(.* )(.*)(\.$)','$4') column3
    ->    FROM data;

+------------------------------------+---------+---------+
| column1                            | column2 | column3 |
+------------------------------------+---------+---------+
| BKT, CAB, TIRES                    | 250     | HRS     |
| FRONT BKT, REAR BKT, CAB, TRACKS   | 1,234   | HRS     |
| FORKS, MAST, CAB, 20 HP ENG, TIRES | 25,102  | HRS     |
+------------------------------------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, that gets me closer but i'm still not quite getting the expected results, I have updated my question to show the progress I have made.

Comment: Following up a little late here...if you have a moment to respond, I’d be curious to know whether my revised answer was of any help or if you were able to solve the problem using a different approach.